# tidying an Igraph plot

Tags: r, igraph

Given the following two vectors for a plot construction, one of edges and one of weighs respectively:

```
edg <- c("ES1-3", "ES4-6", "ES4-6", "ES6-8", "ES6-8", "ES7-9", "ES7-9", 
"ES10-12", "ES10-12", "ES13-15", "ES13-15", "ES16-18", "ES16-18", 
"ES19-21", "ES19-21", "ES22-24", "ES22-24", "ES25-27", "ES25-27", 
"ES28-30", "ES28-30", "ES31-33", "ES31-33", "ES34-36", "ES34-36", 
"ES37-38", "ES13-15", "SA1-3", "SA1-3", "SA4-6", "SA4-6", "SA7-9", 
"SA7-9", "SA10-12", "SA10-12", "SA13-15", "SA13-15", "SA16-18", 
"SA16-18", "SA19-21", "SA19-21", "SA22-25")
```

Plotting code with the above vector:

```
g1 <- make_graph(edges=edg)
```

And the weight vector:

```
E(g1)$weight = c(0.0051, 0.0022, 0.0152, 0.0257, 0.0039, 0.0109, 0.012, 
0.0275, 0.0108, 0.029, 0.0061, 0.0134, 0.0205, 0.0129, 0.0081, 0.0035, 
0.02, 0.0094, 0.0095, 0.0161, 0.0199)
```

Now please have a look at the plot I get as a result with the code below:

```
 plot(g1,
 edge.label = E(g1)$weight,
 edge.arrow.size=.4,
 vertex.color='orange',
 vertex.size=7, 
 vertex.frame.color="orange",
 vertex.label.color="black", 
 vertex.label.cex=0.8,
 vertex.label.dist=1.1,
 margin=-.2,
 vertex.shape='circle')
```

[image]

I have several issues on this plot I cannot address correctly:

1. Despite giving a constant for `edge.arrow.size=.4` the edge arrow sizes have different sizes, i.e, some arrows are bigger than others and I would like to have them all with the same size.
2. I would like to color code with a different color the right branch of 'SA's' i.e 'SA1-3' 'SA4-6' and so forth. I read it has something to do with creating an attribute just like the vector of weights I have created but could not figure that out correctly.
3. I would like to have a neater graph, that is, non-overlapping edge labels with the numbers that should be above the arrows. I tried tweaking several parameters as you can see on the `plot(g1,...)` code, but none of them had given a decent and neat graph that is good looking.
4. Every time I run the `plot(g1,...)` code described below on R I get a different shape of a graph. That is the branch sizes change, for instance the branch that was on the left turns out to be on the right and vice-versa. Why is that ? Why `igraph` keeps on giving me different shapes for the same code every time I run the code without modifying anything ??

Comment: *Why igraph keeps on giving me different shapes*? Try `set.seed(<int>)` before calling `plot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @RuiBaradas commented, there is a random element to the default layout. In order to make the layout repeatable, you must either specify the layout explicitly or set the seed with something like `set.seed(123)`.  However, you have many competing labels on your graph.  Almost anything that you do at random will have problems, so I am going to recommend that you make an explicit layout. I will show that below. To change the vertex colors, you just need to specify a vector of colors instead of a single constant. That is also shown below. I also adjusted `vertex.label.dist` and `vertex.label.degree` to control the position of the labels relative to the nodes.  I am not seeing your problem with different arrow sizes.

Using your data:

```
## First make a color map 
ColMap = rep("orange", vcount(g1))
ColMap[grep("^SA", V(g1)$name)] = "red"

## Create an explicit layout of the vertices 
## that will separate the labels
LO = matrix(0, nrow=22, ncol=2)
LO[1:5,1]   = 5:1
LO[7:14,1]  = (1:8)/1.7
LO[15:22,1] = (1:8)/1.7
LO[7:14,2]  = -(1:8)
LO[15:22,2] = 2:9


plot(g1, layout=LO,
  edge.label = E(g1)$weight,
  edge.label.cex = 0.8,
  edge.arrow.size=.4,
  vertex.color=ColMap,
  vertex.size=7, 
  vertex.frame.color="orange",
  vertex.label.color="black", 
  vertex.label.cex=0.8,
  vertex.label.dist=c(rep(1.2,5), rep(2.2,17)),
  vertex.label.degree = c(rep(-pi/2, 5), pi, rep(-0.1,8), rep(0.1,8)),
  margin=-.2,
  vertex.shape='circle')
```

[image: Plot with explicit layout]

Considering how much you are trying to pack into this graph, this does not look too bad. At least, you can read everything.  If you don't like the shape, you can adjust the layout to position things where you want.

Comment: What is the basic idea behind those numbers that compose your matrix when sketching a new layout ? I would flip ES1-3 to ES13-15 to make look like a street fork.

Comment: They are simply x-y coordinates for the vertices.  Your way would give lee space horizontally,  but you can try it out by changing `LO[1:5,1]   = 5:1` to say `LO[1:5,1]   = -5:-1`

Comment: I tried but now only the `ES13-15` got scrambled with the previous number. Is there a way to adjust only the distance of `ES13-15` ?

Comment: Ah yes,  That is not really the distance but the direction. Try changing the vertex.label.degree part to `vertex.label.degree = c(rep(-pi/2, 5), 0, rep(-0.1,8), rep(0.1,8))`